# Impact of the starting kafka service on bootup

Tags: apache-kafka

I have configure the kafka service on auto start on bootup.I wanted to understand the impact of doing so.

1.If service started on the all kafka servers at the same time.
2.If Kafka service auto started before all zookeeper severs started.
3.If Kafka service auto started after some time of gap.

Are there any other impact of starting kafka service on bootup automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The only significant impact would be I/O usage of the machine. The order of the brokers don't matter, but if they start before Zookeeper, they would fail to start at all.